# Satzstellung in "Aufgewachsen mit einer hohen Verunsicherung, hätten die Studierenden ..."

Tags: word-order, style

Aus dem Spiegel-Magazin:

> Wohner hat in den Neunzigerjahren in Berlin studiert, als es noch kein Career Center an der Humboldt-Uni gab. Damals machten sich viele erst gegen Ende des Studiums Gedanken, was sie beruflich anfangen wollen. Heute sei ihre Sprechstunde jede Woche ausgebucht, sagt Wohner. **Aufgewachsen mit einer hohen Verunsicherung, hätten die Studierenden aus ihrer Not eine Tugend gemacht:** "Vielen geht es darum, sich selbst zu verwirklichen und möglichst flexibel zu bleiben."

Hier bezieht sich die Phrase "Aufgewachsen mit einer hohen Verunsicherung" auf das Subjekt des Satzes "die Studierenden", ist aber davon getrennt. Ich finde, dieser Stil macht es nur schwieriger, den Satz zu verstehen. Gibt es Gründe dafür, diese besondere Satzstellung zu benutzen?

Comment: Vielleicht ist es nicht jedem klar: "hätten" ist eine Ersatzform für den Konjunktiv I (indirekte Rede), weil der Konjunktiv I "haben" mit dem Indikativ "haben" identisch ist. Es handelt sich also um keinen Konditionalsatz.

Comment: @Chris Danke, guter Kommentar -- hätte ich eigentlich erwähnen sollen.

Comment: Wenn man die indirekte Rede "zurückübersetzt" in die direkte Rede "Aufgewachsen mit einer [...] Verunsicherung, haben die Studierenden ... gemacht", bleibt eine gewöhnliche [Partizipalkonstruktion](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Form/Partizip.html) übrig. Verstehbar ist das auf jeden Fall - zum Stil kann ich nicht viel sagen.

Comment: @Chris Wenn der Satz der Partizipalkonstruktion laut deiner Referenz genau folgen würde, hieße er: "Mit einer hohen Verunsicherung aufgewachsen, hätten die Studierenden ..." Zugegeben ein kleiner Unterschied, aber ich glaube, dass die Version mit "aufgewachsen" ganz vorne ein bisschen schwerer zu verstehen ist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich halte es schlicht für schlechten Stil. Im Englischen sind diese Konstruktionen üblich, man kann sie auch ins Deutsche übertragen, was aber nicht heißt, dass man das auch tun sollte:

> Shocked by the explosion, the people ran for shelter.
>   ?Erschreckt durch die Explosion, gingen die Menschen in Deckung.
>   Die Explosion erschreckte die Menschen und sie gingen in Deckung.

(http://www.grammaring.com/participle-clauses)

In der deutschen Sprache wirkt das einfach nur sperrig und konterkariert völlig die Dynamik und Hervorhebung, die im englischen Satz besteht.

Dementsprechend sollte der Satz lauten:

> Die Studenten sind in einer Phase der Verunsicherung aufgewachsen, haben/hätten *aber* aus ihrer Not eine Tugend gemacht.

Durch das „aber“ wird dann noch die besondere Leistung der Studenten hervorgehoben.

Wenn ich mich richtig erinnere, wurde es uns angekreidet, wenn wir die Partizipialkonstruktionen 1:1 übersetzt haben und es gilt als Merkmal schlechter Übersetzungen.

Comment: hr erstes Explosionsbeispiel mit der Partizipialkonstruktion erscheint mir perfekt elegant. Die Alternative "*Die Explosion erschreckte die Menschen und gingen in Deckung." ist unmöglich ("Die Explosion gingen in Deckung"?) und sollte heissen "Die Explosion erschreckte die Menschen, und sie gingen in Deckung". Das erscheint mir persönlich aber etwas "einfach" und holprig.

Comment: @wolfgang: War ein schlichter Fehler.

Comment: @Veredemon: Kann vorkommen. Vor "und" kommt glaube ich ein Beistrich, wenn ein neues Subjekt kommt (oder war das alte Rechtschreibung?).

Answer (score 4):

Es ist schwer eine Begründung zu finden, wenn keine Alternative zu dem Satz geboten wird.

Ich finde den Satzbau entsprechend der chronologischen Abfolge der Ereignisse geschickt und stolperte beim Lesen nicht darüber, sondern eher über das Komma.

Comment: Ich glaube aber, dass das Komma in diesem Satz notwendig ist.

Comment: Ich darf aber trotzdem darüber stolpern! *faust schüttel*

Comment: ich finde das Komma auch komisch.